# How to use ES6 Fat Arrow to .filter() an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to use ES6 arrow function with `.filter` to return adults (Jack & Jill). It appears I cannot use an if statement.

What do I need to know in order to do this in ES6?

```
var family = [{"name":"Jack",  "age": 26},
              {"name":"Jill",  "age": 22},
              {"name":"James", "age": 5 },
              {"name":"Jenny", "age": 2 }];

let adults = family.filter(person => if (person.age > 18) person); // throws error

(8:37) SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (8:37)
|let adults = family.filter(person => if (person.age > 18) person);
```

My working ES5 example:

```
let adults2 = family.filter(function (person) {
  if (person.age > 18) { return person; }
});
```

Comment: (8:37) SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (8:37)
|let adults = family.filter(person => if (person.age > 18) people);

Answer (score 262, accepted):

> It appears I cannot use an if statement.

Arrow functions either allow to use an **expression** *or* a **block** as their body. Passing an expression

```
foo => bar
```

is equivalent to the following block

```
foo => { return bar; }
```

However,

```
if (person.age > 18) person
```

is not an expression, `if` is a statement. Hence you would have to use a block, if you wanted to use `if` in an arrow function:

```
foo => {  if (person.age > 18) return person; }
```

---

While that technically solves the problem, this a confusing use of `.filter`, because it suggests that you have to return the value that should be contained in the output array. However, the callback passed to `.filter` should return a *Boolean*, i.e. `true` or `false`, indicating whether the element should be included in the new array or not.

So all you need is

```
family.filter(person => person.age > 18);
```

In ES5:

```
family.filter(function (person) {
  return person.age > 18;
});
```

Comment: Ah, what a great explanation. In .filter() if nothing is returned for an object, it's assumed as false? For example, in your ES5 example, only the true elements are returned.

Comment: @HenryZhu: Yes. But my example always returns either `false` or `true`, since `person.age > 18` is always either `false` or `true`.

Comment: The version with the "un-blocked" if was supposed to return `person` (of course it doesn't do that as you pointed...). Had your first correction actually done that (`foo => {  if (person.age > 18) return person }`), you'd get the exact equivalent of what OP used in the ES5 code. While that's a confusing code, it DOES work, and WILL solve the problem. `return person` will coerce to `true`, and no return will "return" `undefined`, which will be coerced to `false`.

Comment: @Amit: Sure. I thought because the other answer suggested it, I wouldn't have to. However, this may be confusing, so I updated it.

Comment: Also there is a nice place to ternary expression `person.age > 18 ? 'a': 'b'`

Comment: @just-boris: Not sure what this would achieve here with `.filter`. Do you mean arrow functions in general?

Comment: @FelixKling, yes in, general. It also works well in `map`, `reduce` and other places for arrow function. Here comparison is enough

Comment: filter() is actually ES5 not ES6

Comment: @CarlosMafla: did anyone claim it was ES6?

Comment: @FelixKling sorry, I don't even remember why I made that comment, I probably misread something.

Answer (score 55):

You can't implicitly return with an `if`, you would need the braces:

```
let adults = family.filter(person => { if (person.age > 18) return person} );
```

It can be simplified though:

```
let adults = family.filter(person => person.age > 18);
```

Comment: Awesome, the second one works. The first one returns an empty array. Any ideas?

Comment: @HenryZhu: It works just fine (probably something else is wrong with your code or transpiler). But that's not the right way anyway.

Comment: How would this be done in the case that you have an else statement?  I am trying to see this with a ternary but cannot seem to identify the correct syntax

Comment: @stevek Exactly like you would with a normal function like in the first example.

Answer (score 5):

```js
return arrayname.filter((rec) => rec.age > 18)
```

Write this in the method and call it

Answer (score 3):

As simple as you can use `const adults = family.filter(({ age }) => age > 18 );`

```js
const family =[{"name":"Jack",  "age": 26},
              {"name":"Jill",  "age": 22},
              {"name":"James", "age": 5 },
              {"name":"Jenny", "age": 2 }];

const adults = family.filter(({ age }) => age > 18 );

console.log(adults)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for those who use `hook`; If you are listing items in your grid and want to remove the selected item, you can use this solution.

```
var list = data.filter(form => form.id !== selectedRowDataId);
setData(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is use the ternary operator like as filter in the map and use the filter for take off the nulls value

```js
var family = [{"name":"Jack",  "age": 26},
              {"name":"Jill",  "age": 22},
              {"name":"James", "age": 5 },
              {"name":"Jenny", "age": 0 }];
              
let adults = family.map(person => person.age < 18?person:null).filter(Boolean);

// or if you are afraid about filter(Boolean) you could use filter(person => person != null);

adults.forEach(element => console.log(element))
```