# How to Filter Items By Category, queryParams in Angular 2 or 4

Tags: angular, query-string

How can I get filter by category to work on an Angular component with a list of Products? 
Here's what my product model looks like:

```
 export interface Product {
    id: number;
    categoryId: number;
 }
```

Getting products from the service looks like this:

```
// Products from the API 
  getProducts(categoryId?: number): void {
    if (categoryId) {
      this.productService.getProducts()
        .then(products => this.products = products);
        this.products.filter((product: Product) => {
          product.categoryId === categoryId;
        });
    } else {
      this.productService.getProducts()
        .then(products => this.products = products);
    }
  }
```

And Query Params is written like this:

```
filterProducts(category: Category) {
  this.router.navigate(['/search'], 
    {queryParams: { category: category.id } });
}
```

in url I got this result - `search?category=2` 
After the url is updated with the category id, the product list still returns all the list of items, it does not return only the products with category id of 2.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
  <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <a (click)="filterProducts(category)">
      {{ category.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What do i need to do/add/implement or improve to make the changes in the url (query params), reflect in the list of products?
Here's the link to the page i am working on for better understanding of the problem - https://deaninfotech.herokuapp.com/dashboard/ng/search

Comment: hi did you perfected this feature? Can share the code snippet on how you do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to subscribe to changes in your `queryParams`, and run `getProducts()` on that subscription. Something like the following, in the same component as `getProducts`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

//...

@Component({
    //...
})
export class SomeComponent {    
    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.getProducts(Number(params['category']));
        });
    }

    //getProducts() {}
}
```

**Edit to `getProducts`, per comments.**

You're getting `cannot read "filter" of undefined` since you're setting `this.products` after the promise asynchronously, which is correct, but your filter function is not within that async call. Adjust as follows, which should allow you to keep the function above in your constructor.

```
// Products from the API 
getProducts(categoryId?: number): void {
    if (categoryId) {
        this.productService.getProducts()
            .then(products => {
                this.products = products.filter((product: Product) => product.categoryId === categoryId);
            });        
    } else {
        this.productService.getProducts()
            .then(products => this.products = products);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This unfortunately didn't work on both ngOnInit and inside the constructor block. In constructor block it says cannot read filter for undefined. In ngOnInit it doesn't work and returns no error.
I suppose it's referring to the filter function in the getProducts() method.

Comment: That makes sense, because your `filter` function is called on `this.products`. You're successfully setting that, but setting it asynchronously, whereas `filter` is called synchronously, and thus `this.products` is still undefined at the time. Try the adjustments in the edit above, which should allow you to keep the subscribe in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks, so the error is gone, I have implemented as described and updated. But still doesn't work well, the page goes blank when the category is picked. The URL is updated but the products belonging to that category is still not displayed, the page goes blank. I have updated the app with the latest up please click and test it - https://deaninfotech.herokuapp.com/dashboard/ng/search

Comment: It's a little bit hard to debug without a plunker or something similar, but in looking at Dev Tools for [the compiled code](https://imgur.com/LlzRnMt), it looks like you're adding a console log, so we'd be trying the same thing. I do think I caught the remaining issue, though: the `.filter` function [can either use an expression *or* a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040486/4167438), and we were trying to combine the two. You can actually see this issue in the attached screesnhot, when the TypeScript is compiled to non-ES6 JavaScript. I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks again, I've corrected the code accordingly, something is still not right as I am still getting the same result. I have added a screenshot for you to see - https://imgur.com/a/KNThf 
I have also pushed the latest update on the herokuapp for your verification.

Comment: Nice, the filter change looks good. After stepping through the compiled code, I have one more idea then - we're currently using strict equality, but the result of query params is a `string`, and you've coded your `product.categoryId` as type `number`. This explains why you end up with an empty array.
To solve, you could either use loose inequality, `==`, or, as I've updated the answer above, explicitly convert the param to a `number` type. Since you know the types you're expecting for both values, the explicit conversion seems to be a better practice here.

Maybe this will finally be it? :)

Comment: Mannnn it finally worked! Thank you so much. But there's one more problem. When I click on the Category, it returns the wrong items from another Category. For example clicking on Category 3 as per what's shown in the URL returns products from Category 2. - I have uploaded a test screen pic for you to check - https://imgur.com/a/H9gcU
What do you think I can do to fix this? Trying to post the working version to heroku but the internet is not working well.

Comment: Glad to hear it! And that screenshot is indeed weird, given that the url seems to be definitively pointing to categoryId of "1", while `this.products` appears to have been filtered according to a categoryId of `2`. I'll have to wait until you can get the updated code on heroku, just so I can step through it again. Feel free to message me directly so we can stop the comment chain here until it's fully resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154398/discussion-between-mayorsanmayor-and-jack-koppa).

Comment: Thank you again, I have uploaded the latest update on Heroku, please do check it out. I also sent you a message in chat, please check.