# Query Params Angular 5 routes error

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to use `query params` in angular which uses data provided by service and filter the products in the shop page.

In my shop component -

```
ngOnInit() {
this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();

this.activatedRoute.queryParams
  .subscribe(queryParams => {
    if (queryParams.type === 'jeans') {
       let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> product.productCat == 'Jeans');
       console.log(filteredProduct);
    } else if(queryParams.type === 'shirts') {
       let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> product.productCat == 'Shirts');
       console.log(filteredProduct);
    }
  });
}

redirectPage(value){
    this.router.navigate(['/shop' ,'value']);
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
}
```

In my Other component. I am providing the router link -

```
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']" [queryParams]="{ type: 'jeans'}" (click)="redirectPage('jeans')">Jeans</a>
```

I am giving a path -

```
{path: 'shop/:type', component: ShopComponent},
```

So when the click the anchor tag jeans. The url which shows is `http://localhost:4200/shop?type=jeans` but I am getting an error - `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'shop'`

I am getting the correct data in console log for this logic `let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> product.productCat == 'Jeans');` but I think there is some mistake I'm doing with queryparams or path.

In shop component I have used `*ngFor` for product categories (productCat). Is this causing the problem? -

```
<div class="col-md-10 shop-products" *ngFor="let prod of productList">
        <div class="shop-products-headline">
            <h3>{{prod.productCat}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row shop-products-listing">
            <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of prod.product">
                <div class="sp-list-inner">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="{{product.productImage}}" alt="{{product.productImageAlt}}">
                            <figcaption>
                                <h5 class="product-inner-title">{{product.productName}}</h5>
                                <p class="product-inner-price">
                                    <span class="new-price"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{product.newPrice}}</span>
                                    <span class="old-price"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{product.oldPrice}}</span>
                                    <span class="you-save">you save <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{product.oldPrice - product.newPrice}}</span>
                                </p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you inside some nested `router-outlet` ?

Comment: No I dont think so - `<app-header></app-header>
<app-categories></app-categories>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters and path are two separate things. 
Path is essentially your URL, query parameters are usually appended after the URL.

> Typical URL containing a query string is as follows:
>
> http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret
>
> When a server receives a request for such a page, it may run a program, passing the query string, which in this case is, name=ferret unchanged, to the program. The question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string.
>
> from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

The simplest fix here is to change your path to `{path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent},`

If you still want to use the path you're using now, use route params (not queryparams).
For your current case, you should change your routerLink to `routerLink="/shop/jeans"` and then get the data from `this.activatedRoute.params`:

```
    productListShow = [];

    ngOnInit() {
    this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();
    this.productListShow = this.productList;

    this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        if (params.type === 'jeans') {
           this.productListShow = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCat == 'Jeans');
        } else if(params.type === 'shirts') {
           this.productListShow = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCat == 'Shirts');
        }
      });
    }
```

Use productListShow instead of productList in shop.html:

`<div class="col-md-10 shop-products" *ngFor="let prod of productListShow">`

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but I am getting this error msg `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'shop/jeans'`

Comment: what is your path for your routing module in this case? from what url do you route to that page, try adding '/' before it so that it becomes '/shop/jeans'

Comment: I havent given any, but in old case `{path: 'shop/:type', component: ShopComponent},` In console log I am getting the desired data. I am using repeat in shop component page for productCat `<div class="col-md-10 shop-products" *ngFor="let prod of productList"> <div class="shop-products-headline"> <h3>{{prod.productCat}}</h3> </div></div>`. May be this is the issue?

Comment: Hi can use something like this to fix it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185327/how-to-filter-items-by-category-queryparams-in-angular-2-or-4

Comment: wait, can you follow up with the problem you're getting at `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'shop/jeans'` first? Also I don't think you'll need the function redirectPage in shop component and `(click)="redirectPage('jeans')` in the other component, there aren't used this way either.

Comment: Hi @Joshua I have removed the `(click)="redirectPage('jeans')` anf function. And, I the path I used was `{path: 'shop/:type', component: ShopComponent},` for `{path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent},` I was getting the error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'shop/jeans'`

Comment: Okay so now what's the remaining problem.

Comment: In shop page it is showing all the data (jeans + shirts) instead of only jeans. The data is not filtering. But in console it is showing only jeans array which is correct

Comment: oh, make your filteredProduct to a property in your component and use that for your *ngFor, if you need the productList unfiltered intially, you should use a private property or a local variable to store the initial product list from the service and use another public property e.g., productListShow to change to the product list that you want to show dynamically

Comment: Hi @Joshua, thanks can you please show me how? It seems little complicated. Apologies for the trouble.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the code snippets needed.

Comment: Hi! I am getting a small error for `this.productListShow`  -- `Type 'Products' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.`

Comment: this.productList.find, change find to filter so it becomes this.productList.filter

Answer (score 1):

Use only (click) method. Remove [routerLink]="['/shop']"
And in this same ts on which anchor is used, write this code:

```
 redirectPage(value){
    this.router.navigate(['/shop' ,value]);
 }
```

And on the page on which you want to redirect write this modified code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();
    let type_value = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
    if (type_value === 'jeans') {
       let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> 
       product.productCat == 'Jeans');
       console.log(filteredProduct);
    } else if(type_value === 'shirts') {
       let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> 
      product.productCat == 'Shirts');
       console.log(filteredProduct);
    }
}
```

I hope you are not writing the redirect and activatedRoute logic on the same component.

Comment: Hi @Prachi, I am getting the url like this `http://localhost:4200/shop/value` and the data in shop page is not filtering. Please help

Comment: Sorry, please read the updated code. Use this.router.navigate(['/shop' ,value]); instead. Use value as variable, not as string.

Comment: Thanks, Its working but data is not getting filtered. But in console log it is showing the desired result. In my shop component I am looping the data . `<div class="col-md-10 shop-products" *ngFor="let prod of productList">
   <div class="shop-products-headline">
    <h3>{{prod.productCat}}</h3>
   </div></div>`. I assumend it will filter only the specific Product category. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: Hi @Prachi can use something like this to fix it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185327/how-to-filter-items-by-category-queryparams-in-angular-2-or-4