# how to add object value after filter in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add object value after filter out javascript

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'fred'
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: 'bill'
}, {
  id: 3,
  username: 'ted'
}];

var obj = {
  id: 3,
  online: true
}

const result = arr.filter((item) => {
  if (item.id === obj.id) {
    return {
      item,
      online: obj.online
    }
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

It should be

```
{
          id: 3, 
    username: "ted", 
      online: true
}
```

Comment: The callback function for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  should return `true` if you want to keep the element or `false` if you don't. It doesn't create new elements or modify existing ones from the return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040396/how-to-use-es6-fat-arrow-to-filter-an-array-of-objects

Comment: It is new question that does not relates to duplicate question why -minus

Comment: @simon, Did you read through the answer in the linked question?. `filter` returns an array, not a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `item.online` inside filter method.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'fred'
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: 'bill'
}, {
  id: 3,
  username: 'ted'
}];

var obj = {
  id: 3,
  online: true
}

const result = arr.filter((item) => {
  if (item.id === obj.id) {
    item.online = obj.online;
    return true;
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: If I want to have only object return instead array return ?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array. You can access the object with `result[0]`.  Or if you know that there will be only one true result, then you can just use a standard for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The OP expected output is a single object. `filter()` returns an array. `find()` finds the first object meeting the criterion returned by the predicate function. It's poor style for the predicate function to have a side-effect.

`find()` the object, then modify it.

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'fred'
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: 'bill'
}, {
  id: 3,
  username: 'ted'
}];

var obj = {
  id: 93,
  online: true
}

const result = arr.find(item => item.id === obj.id)
result ? result.online = true : null
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good answer, though you may need to add a check before `result.online = true` since `Array.prototype.find()` may return `undefined` for item not found. :)

Comment: Agree, @steven7mwesigwa

Answer (score 0):

According to this problem,  `Object.assign()` is more suitable to solve this problem. One by one value assignment creates many boilerplate, needs more effort.

- The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object.
- Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties overwrite earlier ones.

Code block:

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'fred'
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: 'bill'
}, {
  id: 3,
  username: 'ted'
}];

var obj = {
  id: 3,
  online: true
}

function mergeObjByID(item) {
   if (item.id === obj.id){
    //overwrite item value 
    Object.assign(item,obj)
    return true
  }
}

const result = arr.filter(mergeObjByID); 

console.log(result)
```

More about Object.assign() example:

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }
```